# flume still keep the .tmp file and not copying the file completely to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, flume

Hi I am using flume to copy the files from spooling directory to HDFS using file as the channel.

```
#Component names
a1.sources = src
a1.channels = c1
a1.sinks = k1

#Source details
a1.sources.src.type = spooldir
a1.sources.src.channels = c1
a1.sources.src.spoolDir = /home/cloudera/onetrail
a1.sources.src.fileHeader = false
a1.sources.src.basenameHeader = true
# a1.sources.src.basenameHeaderKey = basename
a1.sources.src.fileSuffix = .COMPLETED
a1.sources.src.threads = 4
a1.sources.src.interceptors = newint
a1.sources.src.interceptors.newint.type = timestamp

#Sink details
a1.sinks.k1.type = hdfs
a1.sinks.k1.channel = c1
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.path = hdfs:///data/contentProviders/cnet/%Y%m%d/
# a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.round = false
# a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.roundValue = 1
# a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.roundUnit = second
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
#a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.file.Type = DataStream
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.filePrefix = %{basename}
# a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.fileSuffix = .xml
a1.sinks.k1.threadsPoolSize = 4

# use a single file at a time
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.maxOpenFiles = 1

# rollover file based on maximum size of 10 MB
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.rollCount = 0
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.rollInterval = 0
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.rollSize = 0
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.batchSize = 12

# Channel details
a1.channels.c1.type = file
a1.channels.c1.checkpointDir = /tmp/flume/checkpoint/
a1.channels.c1.dataDirs = /tmp/flume/data/

# Bind the source and sink to the channel
a1.sources.src.channels = c1
a1.sinks.k1.channels = c1
```

with the above configuration it is able to copy the files to hdfs but the problem which i am facing is one file is keep staying as .tmp and not copying the complete file content.

Can some one help me what could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `.tmp` file is renamed to it's final name once it is "rolled" by Flume.

All of your rollover settings are 0, which means "keep stream open forever".

Set one or more to non-zero values determine when Flume considers the file complete so that it can close it and open the next.

See the [documentation here on Flume Sinks](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#flume-sinks) for further detail.